# MTP not working on Cyanogenmod OS 11(Yureka Playgod) with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mtp

I have recently bought Micromax Yureka Playgod with Cyanogen OS 11 and after connecting the device to Ubuntu 14.04, I have found that the device is not mounted. But if I enable PTP, it mounts camera folder.

MTP is working fine with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of tools that provide possibility to mount MTP devices in Ubuntu.

I may recommend you to follow this [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702) guide.

As alternative, I may propose you use to use [Airdroid](https://www.airdroid.com/) software - you'll receive possibility to connect your Android phone directly to PC via WiFi.